# Is it possible to specify placeholder text for pre-defined filters in datagrid?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Pre-defined filters on datagrid are great https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid/built-in-filters but is it possible to specify a placeholder text?

Answer (score 0):

Not with the default filters, but you could create a custom one that allows you to do this.

https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid/custom-filtering